# Вывод нулевой записи результатов запроса

Tags: php, sql

Имеется следующий цикл:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$row = $db->get_row($result);
while ($row = $db->get_row($result)) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

Цикл отлично срабатывает, но почему-то нулевая запись не выводится. В чем может быть проблема? Как выводить с нулевой записи?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы перед циклом взяли строку (нулевую), зашли в цикл, снова взяли строку (уже первую), вывели результат.
В итоге то, что взято перед циклом не вывелось.
`$row = $db->get_row($result);` перед циклом не нужен

Comment: Можете показать правильную вариацию исполнения кода? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `$row = $db->get_row($result);` перед циклом уберите